# Mosaic of a Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

```
        Bitmap source = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"lena_std.tif");
        Bitmap dest = new Bitmap(source.Width * 3, source.Height * 3, source.PixelFormat);

        for (int y = 0; y < source.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < source.Width; x++)
            {
                Color clr = source.GetPixel(x, y);
                dest.SetPixel(x, y, clr);

                dest.SetPixel(x, y * 2, clr);
                dest.SetPixel(x * 2, y, clr);
                dest.SetPixel(x * 2, y * 2, clr);

                dest.SetPixel(x * 3, y, clr);
                dest.SetPixel(x, y * 3, clr);
                dest.SetPixel(x * 3, y * 3, clr);
            }
        }

        pictureBox1.Image = dest;
```

I was hoping to obtain a mosaic of Lena like the following:

[image]

But, obtained a distorted image instead:

[image]

What went wrong?

Comment: don't multiply the coordinates, calculate with an offset instead. So not `dest.SetPixel(x, y * 2, clr);` but `dest.SetPixel(x, y + source.Height, clr);`

Comment: @jps, why doesn't my solution work?

Comment: @anonymous because with multiplication you get sparse indexes across the whole width: x2 0,2,4,6,8... x3 0,3,6,9,12.. what you really want are dense indexes, starting from an offset: 257,258,259 etc.

Comment: @anonymous: take a sheet of quad paper, draw a small 3*3 pic and go through your code in mind and mark the result on the paper. Then see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting x+offset instead of x*2. Also, you expect to get 9 images => you should be setting 9 things

```
    for (int y = 0; y < source.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < source.Width; x++)
        {
            Color clr = source.GetPixel(x, y);
            dest.SetPixel(x, y, clr);

            dest.SetPixel(x, y + source.Height, clr);
            dest.SetPixel(x + source.Width, y, clr);
            dest.SetPixel(x + source.Width, y + source.Height, clr);

            dest.SetPixel(x + (source.Width*2), y, clr);
            dest.SetPixel(x, y + (source.Height*2), clr);
            dest.SetPixel(x + (source.Width*2), y + (source.Height*2), clr);

            dest.SetPixel(x + (source.Width*2), y + source.Height, clr);
            dest.SetPixel(x + source.Width, y + (source.Height*2), clr);
        }
    }
```

Would this work for you?

Comment: @anonymous because with multiplication you get sparse indexes across the whole width: x2 0,2,4,6,8... x3 0,3,6,9,12.. what you really want are dense indexes, starting from an offset: 257,258,259 etc.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting exactly what you're asking for :) For instance, for x and y being 0, you set the pixel at (0,0) seven times (and not nine). You need to offset with the image width and height.

Replace the SetPixel statements with something, for a 3x3 mosaic, in the lines of

```
for (j=0; j<3; j++)
  for (i=0; i<3; i++)
     dest.SetPixel(i*source.Width+x, j*source.Height+y, clr);
```

All in all:

```
for (y = 0; y < source.Height; y++)
    for (x = 0; x < source.Width; x++)
    {
        Color clr = source.GetPixel(x, y);
        for (j=0; j<3; j++)
           for (i=0; i<3; i++)
              dest.SetPixel(i*source.Width+x, j*source.Height+y, clr);    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextureBrush to draw tiles:

```
Image image =  (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"lena_std.tif");
TextureBrush tBrush = new TextureBrush(image);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200));
```